# Prolog, counter

Tags: prolog, counter

I want to calculate , in two lists (same lenght), the number of elements that are equal and in the same position. 
For example:
Lets say we have the lists A = [3,6,7,9]  and  B = [2,6,4,9], i want to be printed in the screen the message, "2 bulls found".

So far i have made this:

```
bulls([],[]).
bulls([Ha|Ta],[Hb|Tb]) :-
    Ha = Hb,
    writeln('bull found'),
    bulls(Ta,Tb);
    bulls(Ta,Tb).
```

Every time an element that exists in the same place in both lists, the message 'bull found' is printed.
And in my mind i want to make something like this:

```
bulls([],[],_).
bulls([Ha|Ta],[Hb|Tb],Counter) :-
    Ha = Hb,
    NewCounter is Counter + 1,
    bulls(Ta,Tb,NewCounter);
    bulls(Ta,Tb,NewCounter).

bulls(List1,List2):- bulls(List1,List2,0).
```

`bulls` is called from another rule that passes the lists two it.
How do i make it so it prints the value of 'bulls' to the screen. Any help?

---

**Edit**
So after **Suki's** post, i made this test program testing 2 lists:

```
bulls([],[],X), write(X), write('bulls found'),fail.
bulls([Ha|Ta],[Hb|Tb],Counter) :-
    Ha = Hb,
    NewCounter is Counter + 1,
    bulls(Ta,Tb,NewCounter);
    bulls(Ta,Tb,NewCounter).

check(List1,List2):- 
    bulls(List1,List2,0).


start:-
    A=[1,1,1,1],
    B=[2,1,2,1],
    writeln(A),writeln(B),
    check(A,B).
```

and i get this result

```
1 ?- start.
[1,1,1,1]
[2,1,2,1]
ERROR: bulls/3: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your edited program:

The first clause is not a clause, it's a goal! It should look like this:

```
bulls([],[],X) :- write(X), write(' bulls found').
```

You should drop the `fail`, btw.

In the second clause, you need to use "if-then-else", and use `Counter` instead of `NewCounter` in the "else"-branch:

```
bulls([Ha|Ta],[Hb|Tb],Counter) :-
  (
    Ha == Hb
  ->
    NewCounter is Counter + 1,
    bulls(Ta,Tb,NewCounter)
  ;
    bulls(Ta,Tb,Counter)
  ).
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. No i dont get an error but the output is not what i was expecting. I jest get `1 ?- start.
[1,1,1,1]
[2,1,2,1]
false.`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the predicates findall, length, nth0 exist in your prolog implementation:

(The trace below is from swi-prolog)

```
A = [3,6,7,9], 
B = [2,6,4,9], 
findall(Y, ((nth0(X, A, Y), nth0(X, B, Y))), Y),
length(Y, LenY),
write(LenY), write(' Bulls Found').

[trace]  ?- A = [3,6,7,9], 
B = [2,6,4,9], 
findall(Y, ((nth0(X, A, Y), nth0(X, B, Y))), Y),
length(Y, LenY),
write(LenY), write(' Bulls Found').
   Call: (7) _G2814=[3, 6, 7, 9] ? creep
   Exit: (7) [3, 6, 7, 9]=[3, 6, 7, 9] ? creep
   Call: (7) _G2829=[2, 6, 4, 9] ? creep
   Exit: (7) [2, 6, 4, 9]=[2, 6, 4, 9] ? creep
^  Call: (7) findall(_G2834, (nth0(_G2832, [3, 6, 7, 9], _G2834), nth0(_G2832, [2, 6, 4, 9], _G2834)), _G2834) ? creep
   Call: (13) lists:nth0(_G2832, [3, 6, 7, 9], _G2834) ? creep
   Exit: (13) lists:nth0(0, [3, 6, 7, 9], 3) ? creep
   Call: (13) lists:nth0(0, [2, 6, 4, 9], 3) ? creep
   Fail: (13) lists:nth0(0, [2, 6, 4, 9], 3) ? creep
   Redo: (13) lists:nth0(_G2832, [3, 6, 7, 9], _G2834) ? creep
   Exit: (13) lists:nth0(1, [3, 6, 7, 9], 6) ? creep
   Call: (13) lists:nth0(1, [2, 6, 4, 9], 6) ? creep
   Exit: (13) lists:nth0(1, [2, 6, 4, 9], 6) ? creep
   Redo: (13) lists:nth0(_G2832, [3, 6, 7, 9], _G2834) ? creep
   Exit: (13) lists:nth0(2, [3, 6, 7, 9], 7) ? creep
   Call: (13) lists:nth0(2, [2, 6, 4, 9], 7) ? creep
   Fail: (13) lists:nth0(2, [2, 6, 4, 9], 7) ? creep
   Redo: (13) lists:nth0(_G2832, [3, 6, 7, 9], _G2834) ? creep
   Exit: (13) lists:nth0(3, [3, 6, 7, 9], 9) ? creep
   Call: (13) lists:nth0(3, [2, 6, 4, 9], 9) ? creep
   Exit: (13) lists:nth0(3, [2, 6, 4, 9], 9) ? creep
^  Exit: (7) findall([6, 9], user: (nth0(_G2832, [3, 6, 7, 9], [6, 9]), nth0(_G2832, [2, 6, 4, 9], [6, 9])), [6, 9]) ? creep
   Call: (7) length([6, 9], _G2848) ? creep
   Exit: (7) length([6, 9], 2) ? creep
   Call: (7) write(2) ? creep
2
   Exit: (7) write(2) ? creep
   Call: (7) write(' Bulls Found') ? creep
 Bulls Found
   Exit: (7) write(' Bulls Found') ? creep
A = [3, 6, 7, 9],
B = [2, 6, 4, 9],
Y = [6, 9],
LenY = 2.
```